# ray_cast in blender 2.93

Tags: python, rendering

I am new to Blender, and I use Blender 2.93 with Python. I have a sphere and camera in my scene. I want to detect if the sphere has a direct ray_cast hit or not. I tried to use both obj.ray_cast and scene.ray_cast, but I did not know which coordinate system to use.

[image]

Comment: 2.93 is a very old version. What's the reason for using such an outdated version?

Comment: I have some  functionalities  (from my seniors) in 2.93 which are hard to migrate to the latest version

Comment: I would recommend finding a way to move to current version. You will run into problems with outdated software. For example, answering questions about this old version would probably require downloading it to check how things used to work so a lot of people might be discouraged from looking into your problem. I know I am.

Comment: Version 2.93 is officially supported as Long Term Support until June 2023 so I don't think it's fair to say it's an outdated version. https://www.blender.org/download/lts/

Comment: Could you post your script so we have a base to work from ? I don't think the raycast code has been changed much since 2.93.